# Not able to set a common Listener in BlackBerry development

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to set a common listener for an Customized button and Bitmap field.I am able to reach in listener but not able to differentiate between two fields.

```
private class MeaningsDetailsPageListner implements FieldChangeListener{
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int arg1) {
        Dialog.alert("Hi");
        if(field == bField){
            Dialog.alert("Image Clicked");
        }else if(field == wordBtn){
            Dialog.alert("Button Clicked!!");
        }
    }
}
```

In following code wordBtn is my customised button and other is BitmapField.I am getting Hi alert but not able to differentiate further.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the class name of your customized button?

Comment: Using `instanceof` operator may be helpful. Check this, http://pastebin.com/KKCyztG2.

Comment: did you tried field change listener ?

Comment: Hi Rupak that class name is CustomButtonField and it extends Field.

Comment: Hi Rupak its working now.Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I see what you're trying to do, you're better off adding a `FieldChangeListener` to each Field individually as an anonymous class. This way you don't have to worry about casting your Field to the correct type when testing for equality inside `fieldChanged`.

```
ButtonField b = new ButtonField("Hello!");
b.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        Dialog.alert("Button clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: But if fields are not compared then we cannot segregate the Fields type.And my issue is i want to get click on another field when 1 field is clicked and both of them are in same manager.

Comment: Fields are not designed to remember when they have been clicked although they do store whether their state has changed in Field.isMuddy and Field.isDirty. To do this you should probably implement a flag to indicate which fields have been clicked.